# Getting the timestamp from last saturday (every week)?

Tags: php, date

first let me show you my code:

```
$lastWeek = date('m-d-Y', strtotime('-1 week'));
```

That's how to get the timestamp from last week.
Is there a chance I gan get the timestamp from last saturday?

I hope you know what I mean.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: btw 'm-d-Y' is a ridiculous date format :)

Comment: It wasn't my idea to format the date like that :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What's wrong with

```
$last_sat = strtotime("last Saturday");
```

**EDIT**

The time should be set to '00:00:00';

```
echo date('d-M-Y H:i:s',$last_sat);
```

gives

```
29-Jan-2011 00:00:00
```

Comment: @Yehonatan: Clearly you didn't spend long enough on the `strtotime` documentation page, which, of course you were reading when you wrote your initial code, right?!

Comment: @Yehonatan: Oops, sorry, you're not the OP

Comment: It's surprising just what does work with strtotime... try $previous_sat = strtotime("last Saturday - 1 week");  and then there's a few simple date strings that you'd expect to work, but they don't

Comment: @Mark Baker: But how to set the time to 00:00:00? The timestamp of "last Saturday" is always 12 o'clock. "last Saturday -12 hours" does not work - unfortunately :)

Comment: @Forlan07 - see my edit, and check that you're not using h rather than H in the format for your date mask... h will return 12hr clock time (where 00:00:00 is 12:00:00)